# Node/Express app works on server but via proxy, express created 404 error

Tags: node.js, apache, express, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a one file node/express app with 2 post routes being handled. On the server the app and its routes work when accessed via the ip address. However when nginx proxy is pointed to it, by our proxy guy, then we are getting 404 errors which are created by express.

So this leads me to believe that the app is being reached but none of routes are matching with the request I am making, although they do match when accessing via ip address.

Would anybody know what is happening there, and how to correct it?

I would be very grateful for any clues.

Comment: Can you add nginx config? If you need to access it with same URL route, the NGINX will have to map express to `/` in the nginx config something like `location / { .....`

Comment: Thank you ch4nd4n. We shall try that later.